# Condtional fragments and navigation reuse

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

Given N fragments representing different UI of the same entity. The fragments are displayed conditionally. The condition is known only in the runtime. Each fragment should have the same navigation flow.

How to generalize/abstract navigation flow out of fragments for further reuse using Navigation architecture component XML graph? Currently, I see only the way of creating the separate destination or nested navigation for each fragment, but it is the terrible idea in terms of reuse. Another option is to make all conditional transitions in Kotlin/Java code, but in such case the app's flow will not be depicted in the navigation graph schema. Is there a better way to reuse navigation?

Official documentation is quite vaque on this topic: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-conditional

Comment: I also have the same experience do you have any solution to this?

Comment: There is an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773 not fixed yet. You can star it if you want to watch it.

Comment: I dont understand how that issue tracker is related to the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I've missed the question. In terms of this question I haven't found a graceful way, and because of numerous other issues (like at link above), I abandon Navigation lib and switched to https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav. IMO Navigation lib is not ready yet. It seems that the only way to do dynamic graph creation is programmatic. If you want you can create the feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments can be re-used with the **Navigation Architecture Component** in order to keep code efficient.

For instance, I have a nested child Fragment called *ContentFragment* within my *HomeFragment* that contains content. I am re-using the *ContentFragment* to show a different type of content launched on a separate screen.

1. Select **New destination** in the NavGraph design tool to add the Fragment.
   [image]
2. Pass an argument into both the nested Fragment and the Fragment launched with the NavGraph so the Fragment can read the argument and provide the appropriate logic for each case.

a) For the nested Fragment I pass in an argument via the bundle as normal in the pre Navigation Component era with Fragments.

b) For the new screen I select the Fragment added to the NavGraph and click the **+** button in the arguments section. Then you can follow the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Arguments) for adding arguments with the Navigation Component.
[image]

Comment: How do you handle the navigation directions in this case? Let's say ContentFragment is being used in 2 navigation graph.

Comment: @YellowJ, The best strategy is to implement nested navigation graphs for shared screens. _See: [Design navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) and [Nested navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs)_